# How is the Visual Studio 2010 SP1 HTML5 support different than the Gallery download?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, html

Prior to the release of Visual Studio 2010 SP1, there was [HTML 5 Intellisense for Visual Studio 2010 and 2008](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d771cbc8-d60a-40b0-a1d8-f19fc393127d/).  I had download this previously and was using that HTML 5 Intellisense (with some custom modifications to support certain data- attributes I use frequently in my project). After I upgraded to SP1, I checked the .xsd file <strike>which had the same date.  I don't think the HTML5 support has changed.</strike>

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\html\html_5.xsd
```

[Will Visual Studio 2010 support HTML 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682180/will-visual-studio-2010-support-html-5) has some good links, but I can't find anything definiate.

**Edit**: I made an incorrect assumption on the file dates.  Since, I had installed Visual Studio on 1/19/2011 and the SP1 files are dated 1/18/2011, I assumed they hadn't changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a copy of the original html_5.xsd (date 4/1/2010), in a location I assume was for VS2008 support:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Packages\Schemas\Html\
```

I was able to compare the files and WinMerge lists 38 differences.  Some of them are:

- name change from `HTML 5` to `HTML5`
- something related to data- attributes support `vs:customattrprefix="data-"`
- attributes for `audio` and `video` moved from inline to `<xsd:attributeGroup name="mediaAttributeGroup"`
- some `xsd:element` contain custom `vs:disallowedancestor` attribute
- other misc element and attribute changes/additions
- SVG now references external file `<xsd:element name="svg" type="SVG.svg" vs:isxml="true"/>`