# Is it possible to use HTML5 in a ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

For now, I just want to use the `<audio>` and `<video>` tags and maybe try out the drag and drop features since these are supported by Firefox 3.6. The project will just be a test project, not necessarily for production.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The big idea behind ASP.NET MVC is that you have total control over the generated HTML, so you just need to use the tags as you wish, no additional work required.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted a bit more control over the inputs and the ability to use postback on the controls, so I built a suite of [HTML 5 Controls](http://www.html5asp.com).  It's got canvas and just about all of the new input types.  As was said earlier, one big limitation is the browser your user brings to the site.  The inputs will fail gracefully to Input Type="text".

Answer (score 0):

Change the DOCTYPE on your master page to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and ignore any validation errors you get.  I think you'll be ok.

Comment: When do you ever not ignore the validation errors thrown up by the HTML editor in VS?

Comment: I don't ignore them all, but I grant that there a lot that do get ignored.  In fact, I can remove most all of them with a judicious use of `<% if (false) { %>...include CSS links...<% } %> in my partials if I really care.

Comment: Found a HTML5 validation schema for VS 2008 which should eliminate most of the errors. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084194/is-it-possible-to-add-html5-validation-to-visual-studio (first answer)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. You can output whatever HTML you'd like.

The HtmlHelpers may not output your desired HTML but its not that hard to change them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes just change the doctype. but the question is does your users have a browser that supports HTML5 ?