# Can I set HTML5 semantic markup after a project has been created?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm quite new to ASP.NET and Visual Studio. I'm working on an old project, is it possible for me to turn on HTML 5 semantic markup? I've not been able to find the option, I would have expected the option here! :[image: html validation]

**I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate**
The following is a screenshot of the new project dialog.
[image: imgur.com/eaRqt]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add HTML5 validation to Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084194/is-it-possible-to-add-html5-validation-to-visual-studio)

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, that might solve it! But why give the option for HTML5 validation without being capable of it!? http://imgur.com/eaRqt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link to a similar topic containing a variety of answers:
[Is it possible to add HTML5 validation to Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084194/is-it-possible-to-add-html5-validation-to-visual-studio)

Download link for the VS 2010 update which gives HTML5 validation:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83

Answer to my question:
Install the update, and when developing HTML:
Right click > Formatting and Validation > Validation > Target: HTML5.

Alternatively you can select HTML5 from the drop down above the text area, next to the 'Check page for accessibility button'.